# I want to update a database by loading a file into an already existing field, but an error occurs

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from io import BytesIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///filestorage.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class FileContents(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300))
    date = db.Column(db.String(300), default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<File %r>' % self.id


@app.route('/')
def index():
    files = FileContents.query.filter(FileContents.content == None).all()
    return render_template('index.html', files=files)

@app.route('/upload/<int:id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload(id):
    file = FileContents.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file.content = request.files['content']
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Html:

```
<form action="/upload/{{file.id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="content" id="content" value="{{file.content}}">
                <br>
                <input type="image" src="static/css/upload.png" name="submit" width="50" height="50" alt="submit"/>
                </form>
```

An error:

sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'FileStorage'
[SQL: UPDATE file_contents SET content=? WHERE file_contents.id = ?]
[parameters: [{'content': <FileStorage: 'randomfile.docx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')>, 'file_contents_id': 1}]]

the problem appears to be in this line:

```
file.content = request.files['content']
```

Is there any way to pass a "bytes-like object" so that it could be uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Had to put .read() after the problematic line.

```
file.content = request.files['content'].read()
```